# How to merge rows in SQL Report Builder when some rows have columns with no values?

Tags: sql-server-2008, duplicates, rows, reportbuilder3.0

I have been given a rather complex report and asked to update it so that a user can enter values for several parameters (some of which then present selections in multi-value paramenters), in order to generate a list of all computer names with one or more specific software packages installed on them.

A "simplified" version of the main query (shown below) works, but unfortunately the report sometimes lists nearly duplicate rows for the same software package on the same computer; one with an installation date and the other without an installation. There are also records that have no installation date, but do not have a corresponding record with an installation date.

I am able to eliminate rows without installation dates by adding "AND arp.InstallationDate0 IS NOT NULL" to the WHERE clause, but how can I change the query so that if duplicate records exist, only the one with the installation date is displayed, yet if only one record with no installation exists, that record is shown?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sys.Name0 , arp.DisplayName0 , arp.Version0 , arp.InstallDate0 

FROM v_R_System sys 

INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS UNION SELECT * 
  FROM v_GS_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS_64) arp ON sys.ResourceID = arp.ResourceID 

INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership fcm ON sys.ResourceID = fcm.ResourceID 

WHERE arp.DisplayName0 IN (@productname) AND COALESCE (arp.Version0, '') LIKE @version  
  AND fcm.CollectionID IN (@selectcollection) 

ORDER BY sys.Name0
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your install date in an aggregate function and isnull function.

```
max(isnull(arp.InstallDate0, '31-Dec-1900')) as installdate0
```

Be sure to include the `group by` clause also.